# Equivalant in Swift performSelectorOnMainThread waitUntilDone

Tags: ios, http, swift, google-places-api, background-process

I wanted to translate this in swift :

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

    });
```

It's for using google places api.

I wondering about using a simple NSURLSession request but it seems that the dataWithContentsOfURL do the job of an NSURLSession request ?

Someone ?

Answer (score 1):

`dataWithContentsOfURL` is discouraged. You should use `NSURLSession` for asynchronous downloads, or if you prefer the simpler `NSURLConnection`.

The delegate callbacks tell the main thread when the download is finished - so no need to engage with Great Central Dispatch APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Mundi is right that the better tool here is `NSURLSession`. But your code can work; just need to use GCD correctly, and deal with the fact that it might fail:

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue) {
    if let data = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(googleRequestURL) {
      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.fetchedData(data) }
    } else {
      // Here's the problem with dataWithContentsOfURL. You had an error, but you
      // don't know what it was. I guess you'll do something here...
    }
}
```